# How to get specific featured images of the post in wordpress. ?

Tags: php, wordpress, image, post, wordpress-featured-image

In the code below I am trying to extract the exactly featured image of the post_id = 25 but instead, it is pulling new images of the different post.

```
                            <?php 
                            $post_ID= 25;
                            $post_url=  get_permalink($post_ID);
                            $queried_post = get_post($post_ID);
                            ?>
                            <img class="img-circle" src="<?php
                            if (has_post_thumbnail($post_ID)) {
                                the_post_thumbnail('medium');
                            }
                            ?>"
                                 <h2><a href="<?php get_permalink($post_url) ?>"</a><?php echo $queried_post->post_title; ?></h2>

                            <p><?php
                                query_posts('p=25');
                                if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
                                        ?>
                                    <div class="entry">
                                        <?php echo substr(get_the_excerpt(), 0, 300); ?><span>[...]</span>
                                    </div>
                                    <?php
                                endwhile;
                            endif;
                            ?>
                            <p><a class="btn btn-default"  href="#" role="button" >View details &raquo;</a></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use `get_the_post_thumbnail` in order to pass in the id.

```
if (has_post_thumbnail($post_ID)) {
   echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post_ID,'medium');
}
```

`the_post_thumbnail` actually does this:

```
function the_post_thumbnail( $size = 'post-thumbnail', $attr = '' ) {
    echo get_the_post_thumbnail( null, $size, $attr );
}
```

`get_the_post_thumbnail` in turn uses the current post id if null is passed in.

## EDIT

**You just need to change this:**

```
<?php 
$post_ID= 25;
$post_url=  get_permalink($post_ID);
$queried_post = get_post($post_ID);
?>
<img class="img-circle" src="<?php
if (has_post_thumbnail($post_ID)) {
    the_post_thumbnail('medium');
}
?>"
```

**To this:**

```
<?php 
$post_ID= 25;
$post_url=  get_permalink($post_ID);
$queried_post = get_post($post_ID);
?>
<img class="img-circle" src="<?php
if (has_post_thumbnail($post_ID)) {
   echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post_ID,'medium');
}
?>"
```

Comment: Thank you andrew for response. 
I add the function in function.php file and update if (has_post_thumbnail code.... it doesn't work. Now my site is down

Comment: um, no you don't need to add anything to `functions.php` I will edit the answer to make it more clear